# Decoding a JSON into a hash map (top-level key names not known)

Tags: rust, serde

I have a file that I need to parse that contains a JSON file as so:

```
{
  "2123123": "sdjfhasjlkdfhasjldf",
  "2342364": "dsfkjgskdlgfjsödlkfs",
  ...
}
```

These are key hashes with the matching public key. I would like to load it into a `HashMap<String, String>`. I know that I can do a struct like:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Keys {
  key_1: String,
  key_2: String,
  ...
}
```

But this only works if I know a priori the hashes of the keys. I would not like to edit source in order to support adding a new key to the JSON. Is there a simple way to parse a JSON like this directly into a hashmap?

Comment: Just deserialize it directly into a `HashMap` then? Instead of `serde_json::from_str::<Keys>()`, then do `serde_json::from_str::<HashMap<String, String>()`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Probably should do `HashMap<String, serde_json::Value>`, unless it's flat json; but yes deserialize directly to a map

Comment: Once you need `HashMap<String, serde_json::Value>`, I'd probably go all the way and use `serde_json::Value` directly. Feels more consistent to me.